# Dynamic callback URL in Simpleauth

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webapp2

I cant figure out how to specify a dynamic callback url using Simpleauth (https://github.com/crhym3/simpleauth)

I would like to redirect user to whatever page that they were on prior to clicking on Login.

Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 0):

There's two ways you can do this:

1. Store the previous page address in a cookie.
2. Pass in the previous page as a url parameter when going to the login page, and keep track of it through the login process.  You might end up sticking it in a cookie.

Comment: I was hoping for a way to do it through simpleauth setting callback_url, was debating it over the cookie approach. I cant find one more advisable over the other.